# How can I get group chat notifications details on android?

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

I am listening to notifications received by Android phones. I can get info about notifications but I could not find how can I get the notification title which belongs to the chat application.

Let's say I had caught the notification sent from the WhatsApp group chat. When I try to catch its title like this:

```
sbn.notification.extras.getString(EXTRA_TITLE).orEmpty()
```

It gives me the result

```
group name (8 messages): X Person
```

But I would like to know only the group name. How can I handle that problem?

I tried so many things which belong notifications class but I could not find anything.